# How to set encoding result to TextBox

Tags: c#, encoding

How do I set the result of my encoding to a `TextBox`?

```
string myString;
myString = "Hello World";
byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(myString);
textBox1.Text = data.ToString();
```

This displays "System.Byte[]" in the `TextBox`, but I want to instead show the hex result in the `TextBox`.

Comment: Whoever upvoted the question please explain how OP wants to show byte array.

Comment: @Alireza: It's not a duplicate - this person wants to show the actual bytes, not the string representation.

Comment: @Ian: the duplicate question covers all the possible ways to display a `byte[]` as a string, including the actual bytes.

Comment: @Ian the question proposed by Alireza does cover all options in second answer. It is essentially the same as Jon Skeet's (+1) answer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't set the encoding of a text box, but it sounds like you're just trying to display some binary data in a text box... did you want hex, for example? If so, [`BitConverter.ToString(byte\[\])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a733s97(v=vs.110).aspx) is your friend:

```
textBox1.Text = BitConverter.ToString(data);
```

... will give you something like `48-65-6C-6C-6F-20-57-6F-72-6C-64`. You can using `string.Replace` to remove the hyphens if you want, e.g.

```
textBox1.Text = BitConverter.ToString(data).Replace("-", " ");
```

There are alternative representations of binary data as text, of course. For example, you could use base64:

```
textBox1.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(data);
```

But I *suspect* hex is what you're after.

Comment: thank's man
yap im looking for hex...

Answer (score 2):

Am I correct you're looking for a hex-dumping of your bytes? If yes, try something like this:

```
textBox1.Text = BitConverter.ToString(data);
```

Comment: thank's 
yap im looking for hex...

Answer (score 1):

To get the `string` result for the `byte[]`, you can use:

```
textBox1.Text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data)
```